# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly" Error

I looked through most of the similar questions but found no answer to what I'm looking for, so I'm asking a new one.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 105.84,
        "lat": 21.59
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 20.31,
        "pressure": 1010.36,
        "humidity": 98,
        "temp_min": 20.31,
        "temp_max": 20.31,
        "sea_level": 1026.71,
        "grnd_level": 1010.36
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.86,
        "deg": 124.5
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.3075
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "dt": 1482264413,
    "sys": {
        "message": 0.0114,
        "country": "VN",
        "sunrise": 1482190209,
        "sunset": 1482229157
    },
    "id": 1566319,
    "name": "Thai Nguyen",
    "cod": 200
}
```

And here is my code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid={MyAppID}";
     HttpWebRequest httpWebRequset = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     httpWebRequset.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
     httpWebRequset.ContentType = "application/json";

     HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequset.GetResponse();

     using (var StreamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
     {
         string responseString = StreamReader.ReadToEnd();

         ResponseData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(responseString);

         ShowTemp.Text = data.main.temp + "°C";
         ShowWheater.Text = data.weather.description;
    }
}
```

When ever I try to get a temperature I can find it, but when I want to get the description from:

```
{
    ...
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

I get the error.

Comment: Show your `ResponseData` class.

Comment: What does the ResponseData class look like?  I suspect that it is expecting a weather object formatted like '{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}'.  The square brackets that you are trying to parse into the weather object means it is trying to read in an array of objects.

Comment: Indeed, in your root object for this class you likely need something like `public List<Weather> weather {get;set;}` where `Weather` is a class with properties like `id` and `description`.

Comment: here are my responseData   

class ResponseData
    {
        public Main main;
        public Weather weather;
    }

    class Main
    {
        public string temp;
    }    

    public class Weather
    {
        public string description;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON contains an array of `Weather`, even if it only has one entry. This is denoted by the square brackets, see below:

> "weather" : **[**
>   {
>   "id":500,
>   "main":"Rain",
>   "description":"light rain",
>   "icon":"10n"
>   }
>   **]**

You said this was your `ResponseData` class:

```
class ResponseData 
{ 
    public Main main; 
    public Weather weather; 
} 

class Main 
{ 
    public string temp; 
} 

class Weather 
{ 
    public string description; 
}
```

Change the `ResponseData` class to this:

```
public class ResponseData 
{ 
    public Main main { get; set; } 
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; } // This is a List<T> of Weather
}                                              // It can contain more than one entry 
                                               // for weather

public class Main 
{ 
    public double temp { get; set; } // This is a double
} 

public class Weather 
{ 
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

You must also have a reference to `System.Collections` added to your project and the relevant `using`:

```
using System.Collections;
```

As the Weather is now a list you must access it by index like this:

```
ShowWeather.Text = data.weather[0].description;
```

Comment: Now i get this error    'List<Weather>' does not contain a definition for 'description' and no extension method 'description' accepting a first argument of type   'List<Weather>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My bad, think I just forgot the get/set

Comment: Is any code in the IDE underlined in red to show an error? It sounds like you're maybe missing a reference to the library containing `List<T>`. Add a reference to `System.Collections` and put the using at the top of your code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: it has red under line where my code went at   ShowWheater.Text = data.weather. *description*;

Comment: You probably want `ShowWeather.Text = data.weather[0].description;` as Weather is now a list containing one object so you must access the first entry by index.